# Receive notification for the wrong iPhone App

Tags: iphone

I have created two different iPhone application with two different push notification certificate, when i send a notification to app A i received it fine, but when i send it to app B the app A receive it !

i know im not specific enough but i need a general idea of where and what may couse this behavior.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe the problem occurs on your server. As far as I know you have to specify your app id and device id if you want to send a message. Maybe you have copy & pasted them from one to another. Or you have the same identifier in your App. It should be something like register for notification.